# How to properly do http request in Python with headers and data

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch something according to the documentation written here:

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json

post_data = {"exchange": "NSE",
        "tradingsymbol": "INFY",
        "transaction_type": "BUY",
        "variety": "regular",
        "product": "CNC",
        "order_type": "MARKET",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "trigger_price": 0
            }


header_data = {
     'X-Kite-Version': '3',
    'Authorization': 'token '+str(api_key)+":"+str(access_token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post('https://api.kite.trade/margins/orders',
                   data= post_data,
                   headers=header_data)

print(r.text)
```

But I am getting this response

> {"status":"error","message":"invalid json","data":{},"error_type":"InputException"}

I wonder, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but it looks like the input data should be a list/array, rather than a dict/object. So try this for the data:

```py
post_data = [
    {
        "exchange": "NSE",
        "tradingsymbol": "INFY",
        "transaction_type": "BUY",
        "variety": "regular",
        "product": "CNC",
        "order_type": "MARKET",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "trigger_price": 0
    }
]
```